# Prove that if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, then for $n > k$, $f[x_0,x_1,...,x_n] = 0$.

Tags: numerical-methods

I've been struggling with divided difference problems a lot. I'm able to program an algorithm to compute them easily, but I have no idea how to even start this proof. Any ideas?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104446/discussion-on-question-by-cameron-potter-prove-that-if-f-is-a-polynomial-of-de).